# How to disable creation of $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python for python3 virtualenvs?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I develop Python3 on GNU/Linux, but my system has two interpreters installed:

- python2 -> /usr/bin/python
- python3 -> /usr/bin/python3

(AFAIK: This is normal on a Linux box, other installed applications frequently depend upon different versions of Python: either 2 or 3.)

When I create new virtual environments for Python3, I notice the `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin` folder has (at least) two python binaries:

- `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python3` -> copied from /usr/bin/python3
- `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python`-> symlink to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python3`

I don't want the `python` symlink, as it hides my Python2 interpreter in `/usr/bin/python`.

Is there a way to disable the creation of symlink `python` in the new Python3 virtual environment?

(For the time being, I run `virtualenv`, then manually delete `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python` myself.)

Comment: So you *don't* want `python` within the `virtualenv` to access the interpreter you created it to use? Doesn't that make everything more difficult?

Comment: The symlink is *supposed* to hide the system interpreter, so that everything you run in the virtualenv uses the interpreter you specified when you created it. It's not clear *why* you want the behaviour to be otherwise; it could cause some unexpected side effects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Clarified.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't. *"I don't want the python symlink"* - why? *"it hides my Python2 interpreter in `/usr/bin/python`"* - that's the idea!

Comment: Do you use **activate** to access the virtual env? I always use my venvs by starting python with **./env/bin/python** that way you are sure what is being started.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the virtual env is to allow the use of required version as default. That's why you see the symbolic link created.

If you want both (i.e no symbolic link python -> /usr/bin/python3) then do not create virtual env